# Webpage is loading to mid-page position

Tags: php, html, css, onload

I am using an iFrame to import a contact-form PHP page. However, in Firefox and my iPhone, rather than the page loading positioned at the top as normal, the page is loading mid-page to expose the first form field. Example;

http://www.soflorealty.com/help.html

What is actually causing this?
If I can't correct that, is there a work around to force the page to load at the top?

Comment: it would be great if you would provide code rather than let us find your source code

Comment: also, you have a div called content above the I frame, which could cause this issue if it is styled incorrectly

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know which source codes to provide?  The HTML, CSS or PHP?  I figured I would reduce the page to its basic components for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be caused by the first input on the form that is on the iframe, this input has the html5 `autofocus` attribute. Try removing that attribute and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!! Thank you!   I guess all that did was highlight on field onLoad??  Which is not crucial whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing a div with a fixed height just before the div containing the iframe.

Take out that div, and your problem should be solved.

Comment: I did that to create the depth.  Even as I replace the height with line-breaks, the problem persists.